# There aren't [ many / any / no ] young people in our apartment block. (It's 'many' but..... Why not 'any'?)

Tags: grammar, modifiers

I have the above question in one of my classes but can't find a reason as to why the answer can't be 'There aren't any young people.... '

The only thing I can think of is if it something like you can't assume that there are no young people in a building - statistically unlikely - or something like that.

Is there a rule that I don't know?

Cheers.

Comment: I know of nothing wrong with _there aren't any_, at least colloquially. In more formal language _there are no_ would be better.

Comment: What makes you think that 'any' is incorrect here? _It's not._

Answer (score 1):

*Aren't many* implies that the number of young people are few but not zero.
*Aren't any* implies that the number of young people are zero.
As Kate points out, *Aren't no* would need to be replaced by *Are no* to avoid the double negative.

Comment: Both *any* and *many* say what you said, but they don't just imply. And Kate removed the contraction without addressing the unjustified double negative.

Answer (score -1):

It's a trick question:

*YOU* (Judas) can't say "There aren't ANY young people in OUR apartment block," because YOU are (presumably) a young person in your apartment block -- so, there's at least one. ;)

Comment: How do you know Judas lives in an apartment block? And if he doesn't, 'There aren't many young people in our apartment block' is equally 'infelicitous as a statement by Judas'. No, the only considerations here have to be grammatical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Good gravy... I don't claim to know where Judas lives - just trying to reason out a justification for the grammatically correct answer to be technically 'wrong'. Maybe the teacher was trying to be cute... A young person could not accurately make the statement: "There aren't ANY young people in OUR apartment block".

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd agree with the DV-er that this sort of reasoning shouldn't be given more than 'comment' status. Possible, but hardly general English usage: more logic-R-us.